# how to do display: block after user login

Tags: jquery, hooks, login

I want a popup (made with jquery) to appear AFTER the user login. And ONLY after login. I have searched google, but its hard to find a solution there. I know there is a hook called something like wp_login, but how can i get a css like display: block into there ?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has a class when the user has been log in to the site.

> .logged-in

You can use that to check with javascript and show the pop up.

This can be hidden if the user has not been logged in.

And if this you want to show only one time of x number of times you can do it with cookies (among other options)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($.cookie('cookiepopupcheck')){ 
        $('#welcome').hide();
    }else {
        $("#close-welcome").click(function() {
            $(".welcome").fadeOut(3000);
            $.cookie('cookiepopupcheck', true);    
        });
    }
});
```

File can be included with [Enqueue](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)
And the this is the file [github project](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Comment: but i only need it to show ONE TIME after login, not every time the page loads. Only 1 time after login.

Comment: Use a Cookie then :) updated the answer.